# How to find all text values in dataframe and put them into list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe which contains both numbers and string values. I am struggling to find an elegant way to extract all strings into list in order to further replace them with NAN. Could you please help me?

Actually i dont understand what is the best way to iterate through all values of pandas dataframe, The only thing i can to is to convert pd. to list. and this looks rather stupid for me.

Comment: If the objective is to get only the numbers you can use `pd.to_numeric(series, errors='coerce')`.

Comment: Not only is the description a bit vague, we're missing the [mcve]. Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through a column like this:

```
import numpy as np
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

Three things are happening here:

- .apply() function lets you apply a function to a dataframe or its column
- lambda lets you iterate over every row
- x is the row or cell value in your case - that you can verify as string or int.

If you want to do this over all columns one by one, I'd modify the same solution below (although its not the most efficient):

```
for column in df.columns:
   df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda x: np.nan if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: why do you need `.apply` here when you can use `pd.to_numeric` ? Juan's answer in the comments is the correct one

Comment: I did say its not the most efficient - if there's more to digit extraction such as converting 'text456' to 456 - you'd have to apply regex and perhaps then its more useful to iterate - for now though, pd.to_numeric does seem like the right choice.